# How to end the infinity_polling() loop, or how to replace it?

Tags: python, telebot

Now, as you understand, the code is not executed beyond the bot.infinity_polling() line, but it is necessary that the code interrogate the telegram bot for incoming messages and go on to execute the main.tochka() function.  How to implement it?  Are there any functions, so to speak, of a one-time bot poll, and not a looped one?

```
import telebot
import asyncio
import config
import main
import time

bot = telebot.TeleBot(config.TOKEN)


@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def start_message(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'We work...')


@bot.message_handler(commands=['qwerty'])
def message(message):
    try:
        bot.send_document(message.chat.id, main.log_file())
    except ZeroDivisionError:
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Твой запрос по понятной тебе причине вызвал в коде ошибку ZeroDivisionError.\n'
                                          'Повтори свой запрос позже, примерно через час ;)')


def log_every_day():
    if main.timer() == '12:00' or '12:01' or '12:02' or '12:03' or '12:04' or \
            '12:05' or '12:06' or '12:07' or '12:08' or '12:09' or '12:10':
        bot.send_document(462809334, main.log_file())


try:
    while True:
        bot.infinity_polling()
        main.tochka()

except TimeoutError:
    print(f'\n==========================================='
          f'===========================================Похоже возникла ошибка подключения к сети.\n'
          f'===========================================Попробую переподкючиться через минуту.'
          f'\n===========================================\n')

    with open(f"log_{main.ti}.txt", 'a') as file:
        print(f'\n==========================================='
              f'===========================================Похоже возникла ошибка подключения к сети.\n'
              f'===========================================Попробую переподкючиться через минуту.'
              f'\n===========================================\n', file=file)
    time.sleep(60)

    while True:
        bot.infinity_polling()
        main.tochka()
```

I've been scouring the internet for the last 3 days looking for an answer.